# intersection in R

Tags: r, apply

I have two tables.

Both tables have only 1 column.

Both have random integer values between 1 to 1000.

I want to intersect these two tables. The catch is I want to intersect the numbers even if they  have a difference of about 10.

```
1st table -> 5 , 50, 160, 280
2nd table -> 14, 75, 162, 360
```

Output ->

```
1st table -> 5, 160
2nd table -> 14, 162
```

How can I achieve this in R

Comment: What format are these tables in?

Comment: I was  traveling.  My table is a dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with the `sapply` function, checking if each element of `x` or `y` is sufficiently close to some member of the other vector:

```
x <- c(5, 50, 160, 280)
y <- c(14, 75, 162, 360)
new.x <- x[sapply(x, function(z) min(abs(z-y)) <= 10)]
new.y <- y[sapply(y, function(z) min(abs(z-x)) <= 10)]
new.x
# [1]   5 160
new.y
# [1]  14 162
```

Comment: Heck, why not `x<-as.integer(x/10)` followed by `intersect` ? :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't think that would capture 9 and 11 (or 5 and 14 in this example).

Comment: I see yr point. My code would only work if yy were multiples of 10. Now I'll have to go off and look for some even stranger approach .

Comment: I don't know why I got 3 votes down for this question.  There are too many bullyists in this site

Comment: @user3683555 my guess is you got downvoted because you didn't post your own attempts at coding this and show where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses the `outer` function (so your 2 tables will need to be reasonably sized):

```
x <- c(5,50,160,280)
y <- c(999,14,75,162,360)

tmp1 <- outer(x,y, function(x,y) abs(x-y))
tmp2 <- which(tmp1 <= 10, arr.ind=TRUE)

rbind(
    x=x[ tmp2[,1] ],
    y=y[ tmp2[,2] ]
)
```

This looks at every possible pair between x and y and computes the difference between the 2 values, then finds those with a difference <= 10.